# Can I get a Taiwan visa from China?

Tags: visas, china, taiwan, sri-lankan-citizens

I am a Sri Lankan citizen currently living in Sri Lanka. I'm planning a short trip to Taiwan this October, and they require us to get visa in advance to enter the country.

To make the matter worse, there is no Taiwan embassy in Sri Lanka. There is a Chinese embassy that issue Chinese visas. I have another 7 day visit planned on this September to China.
I understand China and Taiwan require separate visas, and others visitors to Taiwan usually get their visa in India or Singapore Taiwanese embassies.

1. Is there a Taiwanese embassy in China, that can issue visas to foreign nationals?
2. Do you know how long it would take, and if there is an expedited service available (because I will be staying a few days in China).

Both China and Taiwan visa would be visit visas. I searched many sites about embassies but there were very ambiguous to me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Taiwan has almost no [embassies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_diplomatic_missions_of_Taiwan) left, having lost the battle with the PRC for recognition (with very few, mostly insignificant, exceptions). What are usually present are offices that provide consular services with names such as "Taipei Economic and Cultural Center". China (The People's Republic) has nothing to do with Republic of China (Taiwan) visas, so don't bother contacting their embassy or consulate.

[Here](http://www.boca.gov.tw/ct.asp?xItem=1836&ctNode=777&mp=2) is a link to the ROC government page regarding Sri Lankan citizens.

Since Taiwan does not appear to have representation in Sri Lanka, you'd probably have to send your application and passport off to Delhi or elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Do you think any such office can officially grant visa for Taiwan? I won't be able to go to the Delhi office so I'm trying to see if I can get the visa during my China visit.

Comment: I think you will not be able to get a Taiwan visa in person in China. There is official representation in Hong Kong, and it's possible a travel agency in China could send your documents away to HK for that purpose, but it might take some time and you might have issues being without your passport in China (checking into hotels etc.). I suggest you try to send your documents away by courier to Delhi (maybe your local travel agency has some suggestions) well in advance of departure. Going to Hong Kong and returning counts as leaving China and returning for China visa purposes.

Comment: Thanks Spehro. You've been very kind and helpful. Looks like I have to send the passport to Delhi or some other consulate for that. Once again Thank you very much for this.

Comment: As an added comment, there are now some tourism related representative offices of Taiwan in Beijing and Shanghai. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_diplomatic_missions_of_Taiwan

Answer (score 6):

Travelling to Taiwan from the People's Republic of China (PRC) isn't a simple thing, especially if your return route is also via the PRC. You may find you need a double-entry visa in order to make the return. The PRC can be sticky about the political divide and some travellers have posted in various forums complaining of their treatment.

Taiwan does have a consulate in Hong Kong (within the Lippo Centre on Queensway). For historical reasons, Hong Kong is outside the PRC visa area and treated almost like a separate entity for tourist purposes. You could have your holiday in the PRC, then exit into Hong Kong, apply for your Taiwan visa there, then fly to Taiwan, returning via Hong Kong to Sri Lanka.