# Taiwan visa for Indians working in China

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, taiwan

I am an Indian, working in Shanghai, China. I need to travel to Taiwan for a short visit of around 10 days.  How can I get a visa for Taiwan?

Comment: I'm afraid you need to apply to the Taipei Economic and Cultural Office back in India. Mainland China is obviously not a good place to get a Taiwan visa :-(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I get a Taiwan visa from China?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34421/can-i-get-a-taiwan-visa-from-china)

Comment: @Giorgio not exact duplicate, OP is Indian, that question was for Sri Lankans

Comment: @MarkMayo isn't the premise the same: how to get a visa for Taiwan while in China; would nationality even be relevant?

Comment: I don't know enough about the situation to be fair - it might be

Comment: @Giorgio As the OP is Indian, I think HK would be a better option, as Indians only need pre-registration for HK, instead of a visa for Singapore (and the flight time too).

Comment: @dda Agree, and I'm happy for you to edit my answer, adding that info !

Answer (score 1):

As China considers Taiwan to be part of China, there is no embassy or consulate through which to apply for a visa.

The first option would be to apply at a Taipei Economic and Cultural Center in your home country. You may be able to do closer to your current location, such as in Hong Kong or Singapore (or through a travel agency in either).

Taipei Economic and Cultural Office (India)
No. 34, Paschimi Marg, Vasant Vihar, New Delhi, Phone: +91 11 4607 7777

Taipei Economic and Cultural Office (Hong Kong)
Lippo Centre, 89 Queensway, Tower 1, Room 1106, Phone: 2525.8316

Taipei Representative Office (Singapore)
460 Alexandra Road, #23-00 PSA Building, Phone: +65 6278 6511

An added observation by @dda, to whom thanks, Hong Kong would be a better option as Indian nationals only need to pre-register, rather than the visa required for Singapore (as well as the flight time).